# Obtener un array con todos los datos de una columna en sqlite python

Tags: python, array, base-de-datos, sqlite, sqlite3

estoy necesitando obtener todos los valores de una columna en un array de una base de datos en sqlite3, para luego modificarlos. Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?.
Es una columna con precios, a los que luego se les aumentará un cierto porcentaje, por si es necesaria la aclaración.
Mi idea es obtener los valores de una columna, en este caso, "precios", introducirlos en un array, modificarlos como debe ser, y luego regresarlos a base de datos, modificados. Desconozco si hay una manera más eficiente de hacerlo, es lo que se me ocurrió, si hay una mejor manera es bienvenida.
El nombre de la tabla es product.

```
    def edit_prices(self, percent):
        query = 'SELECT * FROM product'
        percent_add = str(int(percent)*2) #prueba
        parameters = (percent_add)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.edit_wind.destroy()
        self.message['text'] = 'Precios aumentados un {}%'.format(percent)
        self.get_product()
```

Gracias

Comment: Como no agregaste lo que intentaste/investigaste no puedo ayudarte mucho. Te recomiendo que busques en un buscador información sobre la sentencia select y update. Por ejemplo "select sqlite" o "update sqlite" te mostrará varios resultados que son tutoriales.

Comment: Básicamente es tomar todos los valores de una columna y multiplicarlos a todos para sumarle un porcentaje a estos valores. Adjunto código a la pregunta.